# parsing a webpage with java

Tags: java, eclipse, parsing, standard-library

i'm looking to parse the real time rates from this webpage: http://www.truefx.com/ into my java programs, ie, i want the data from the webpage that is refreshed on a second by second basis to be constantly streamed into my program.

I would like to do this using the standard java libraries, if possible. i'm aware of plugins like jsoup and possibly others, but i'd like to not have to download and install the plugins as the computer i'm using's hard drive is based in california and everything but a few core programs, eclipse being on of them, gets deleted every night when the system restarts.

So if anyone knows of a package in the standard eclipse download that can do this, please let me know!  thanks

---

ok so i got this working, but it seems very slow. for example the data will change on a second by second basis, and even though i'm refreshing the webpage that i read from on a second by second basis also (i used thread.sleep(1000)), and then get a new instance of the webpage, it only updates once every minute or so. what gives?

here's what my code looks like (i used what you posted above as my url reader) :

```
 public String getPage(String urlString){
        String result = "";
        //Access the page
        try {
         // Create a URL for the desired page
         URL url = new URL(urlString);
         // Read all the text returned by the server
         BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
         String str;
         while ((str = in.readLine()) != null) {
             // str is one line of text; readLine() strips the newline character(s)
             result += str;
         }
         in.close();             
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }          
        return result;
    }

    public static void main(String[]args){
        int i =0;
        Reading r = new Reading();

    while(true){
        try{Thread.sleep(1000);}catch(Exception e){}
        String page = new String(r.getPage("http://www.fxstreet.com/rates-charts/forex-rates/"));
        int index = page.indexOf("last_3212166");
        //System.out.println(i+page);
        i++;
        System.out.println(i+"GBP/USD: "+page.substring(index+14,index+20));
    }
```

Comment: The standard Java libraries do not have any HTML parsing capabilities.  Also, have you looked into this yourself at all?  Seems like a quick google could have turned that up.  Also, if everything gets deleted nightly, how are you keeping your source code?  Edit:  Actually, it looks like Java does have some built in stuff: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_API_for_XML_Processing

Comment: thanks. i looked into it a bit, but probably could have searched a little harder before asking.

Comment: well its not really that things get deleted but more to do with the classpath being reset, or something. i don't fully understand how the system is set up i just know that you can't change the class path permanently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With *no external API* you can get the page by this function just with importing **[java.net.URL](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/net/URL.html)**

```
static public String getPage(String urlString){
    String result = "";
    //Access the page
    try {
     // Create a URL for the desired page
     URL url = new URL(urlString);
     // Read all the text returned by the server
     BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
     String str;
     while ((str = in.readLine()) != null) {
         // str is one line of text; readLine() strips the newline character(s)
         result += str;
     }
     in.close();             
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
    } catch (IOException e) {
    }          
    return result;
}
```

Then use the **[java.util.regex](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/regex/package-summary.html)** to match the data that you want to get from the page. and parse it into your labels. Don't forget to put all this in a **thread** with a **while(true)** loop, and a **sleep(some_time)** to have second by second informations.